# Extract the unique genres and its count and store in data frame with index key in R programming

Tags: r, indexing, key, unique, extract

I want to ask if the following code is right about to select the unique Genres value and count them:

```
#Import IMDB_data.csv skipping the second row
    read_File = readLines("C:/Users/Evagoras/Downloads/edwisor/R working Directory/IMDB_data.csv")
    Df = read.csv(textConnection(read_File[-2]), header = TRUE, sep=",")

#Select Genre column 
    Df_Genre= subset(Df, select = c("Genre"))

#Select unique values of Genre variable
    Df_Genre_unique=unique(Df_Genre)


#Count unique values of Genre variable
    Df_Genre_unicount= sapply(Df_Genre, function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

What code I must write to store in data frame with index key? I am confused about index key, I must store with a new column having the index key?

Comment: Please provide your data.

Comment: Agree with @Sam. It's impossible for anyone to help you solve the problem unless there is a reproducible example with a subset of your data (e.g. using `dput`), the code you are using, the error you are getting, and what you are expecting to see for a solved problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
d <- table(Df$Genre)
View(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract unique genre you can use below code

```
df = unique(IMDB_data$Genre)
View(df)
```

And to count the unique genre values

```
df1 = length(unique(IMDB_data$Genre)

View(df1)
```